# Problem referencing labels with href

Tags: hyperref, standalone, xr

I am trying to reference certain sections with href in my index (not using the normal index because I wanted to make a custom one), but when clicking on them it just takes me to the top of the main document.

I'm thinkng this may have to do with the fact that the label I'm referencing is in another document: however, I have used standalone and subimport to add them to the document. I tried using the xr package without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

My workaround was to place `\label{art:1}` before the subimport instead of within the document I was subimporting.